# build script on pgsql that gets data from database1 and updates database2

Tags: postgresql

I want to create one strict script that gets data from the table from database1 saves it on some variable, and then inserts this data to another table in database2.
is it possoble?

example:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    data INTEGER;
BEGIN 
    -- Query for database1
    SELECT config INTO data FROM database1.table LIMIT 1;

    -- Query for database2
    UPDATE database2.table SET input_column = data;
END $$;
```

Comment: Not like that. Postgres does not support cross database queries like that as in Postgres databases are separate unlike MySQL where they are just an alias for `schema`. You will have to use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) or better yet [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this cannot be achieved through cross database queries, you can take a hint at it by using the dblink extension which allows you to execute SQL queries on a remote database.

Something along the lines -

```sql
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    data INTEGER;
BEGIN 
    -- Query for database1
    SELECT config INTO data FROM database1.table LIMIT 1;

    -- Query for database2 using dblink
    PERFORM dblink_exec('dbname=database2', '
        UPDATE table SET input_column = ' || data
    );
END $$;
```

the `dblink_exec` function is used to execute an SQL statement in the remote database. Make sure to create the extension first if it isn't there by default, using `CREATE EXTENSION dblink;`.